# libboost_system.so.1.55 vs. 1.54 on armhf (rpi3)

Tags: ros, boost, raspberrypi, armhf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm compiling ROS Kinetic from source for the Raspberry Pi 3. Recently I started getting a lot of these warnings:

```
Scanning dependencies of target rosout
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rosout.dir/rosout.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosout/lib/rosout/rosout
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_system.so.1.54.0, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libconsole_bridge.so, may conflict with libboost_system.so.1.55.0
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_thread.so.1.54.0, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/libconsole_bridge.so, may conflict with libboost_thread.so.1.55.0
[100%] Built target rosout
```

These don't seem to affect anything, but I'd like to understand more about why these started appearing.

Edit: I have headers for 1.55.0 installed via apt, and libraries for 1.54.0 and 1.55.0:

```
pi@raspberry:~$ find / -name libboost_system.so* | less
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_system.so.1.54.0
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_system.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_system.so.1.55.0
pi@raspberry:~$ ls -l /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_system.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Sep 24  2014 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_system.so -> libboost_system.so.1.55.0
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274700/libboost_system.so.1.55-vs.-1.54-on-armhf-(rpi3)/) by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1247 on 2017-10-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-04**:
Do you have multiple versions of Boost installed?

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2017-11-05**:
1.55.0 and 1.54.0, see edits

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2017-11-06**:
Hmmm, looking at /var/log/apt/history.log, it appears that both versions were installed by rosdep. First "apt-get install -y libboost-all-dev", which pulled in all of 1.55, then "apt-get install -y libconsole-bridge-dev" which pulled in 2 libraries from 1.54.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Multiple boost versions on the same machine *can* work, but typically only if you keep them strictly separate. See #q274016 for another question about that and some thoughts.

Did you build the 'other Boost' from sources? It can't have just "turned up" on its own.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0